# Transforming a 2nd order ODE into a hypergeometric equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation

I have the following ODE (which comes from a physics book):

$$\frac{d \chi^2}{d \eta^2}+(k^2+C(\eta) m^2)\chi(\eta) = 0,$$

where $C(\eta)= A+B\tanh(\rho\eta)$ and $k,m,A,B,\rho$ are constants.

The book hints that it is solvable in terms of hypergeometric functions and presents a solution for it.

I would like to check the solution presented in the book but I'm having trouble finding the appropriate transformations that put this ODE in the form of a hypergeometric equation. How can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Follow the method in http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=276:

Let $\begin{cases}t=\dfrac{1-\tanh(\rho\eta)}{1+\tanh(\rho\eta)}\\x=\chi t^{\pm\frac{\sqrt{m^2(B-A)-k^2}}{2\rho}}\end{cases}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The link you posted is broken, but I managed to find it online and saw your tip there. I'm posting the book name in this comment in case anyone stumbles across this question.

Handbook of exact solutions  for ordinary differential equationsnd ed. - Andrei D. Polyanin and Valentin F. Zaitsev